# Composer running out of "unlimited memory"

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, whm

Disclaimer: I am a SHELL noob.

## Goal

Install the [Drupal Address module](https://www.drupal.org/project/address).

## Tried

**Attempt 1**: `composer require drupal/address`

Returns:

```
Using version ^1.3 for drupal/address
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 435945472) (tried to allocate 2254277 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 270
```

(This is expected as `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` returns `128M`.)

**Attempt 2**: `php -d memory_limit=-1 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer  require drupal/address`

Returns:

```
Using version ^1.3 for drupal/address
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 435683328) (tried to allocate 1069411 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 419
```

**Attempt 3**: `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar  require drupal/address`

```
Using version ^1.3 for drupal/address
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 435945472) (tried to allocate 1069279 bytes) in phar:///home/venturec/public_html/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 419
```

## Notes

- Only able to access the command line through SSH after running [`whm.mydomainname.com/cpsessSESSIONID/scripts2/doautofixer?autofix=safesshrestart`](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/ssh-connection-denied.597415/)
- Composer is located at `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer` and <strike>accidentally installed</strike> have `composer.phar` in the root directory as well.
- All commands were ran in the root directory of my Drupal install public_html

## Resourses

**`composer diagnose`**:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: *Blur*
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: *Blur*
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.6.3
PHP version: 5.6.34
PHP binary path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php
```

**`composer.json`**

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/address": "^1.3"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.4"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Drupal running in a shared host with limited CPU/memory allocatable under your account. Having directive "*memory_limit*" set to "*-1*" doesn't mean that you could use "unlimited" memory in your PHP scripts/commands, it only means that you can use all the memories you can allocate on that host, which is only 435+M (probably around 512M).

If you want to stay with that shared host, there isn't much you can do. Drupal needs enough memory to run, and there isn't much way to optimize Drupal on a shared host. However, you can still try following suggestions:

1. If PHP 7 is available on that host (you may check it in cPanel), try to run Drupal under PHP 7 instead. This allows to run Drupal with less memory.
2. Instead of maintaining Drupal with *Composer*, you may manually download the module, upload it to the host, then enable it in Drupal admin panel.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Currently, that project is put aside, but I'll reply once I get back to it. I'm also exploring cPanel's Shell Fork Bomb Protection. Thanks again!